# Unable to filter word inside the filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried the filter word using toLowerCase method and i tried to filter domain names. But i am getting the empty array.  i used toLowerCase method to convert if the data having capital word or user search by capital word.
below is my code.

```js
var data = [ {
  "name": "test",
  "domain": "domain2",
  "subdomain": "subdomain5",
  "type": "yes"
 },
    {
  "name": "test",
  "domain": "domain2",
  "subdomain": "subdomain6",
  "type": "no"
 },
    {
  "name": "hello",
  "domain": "domain2",
  "subdomain": "subdomain6",
  "type": "no"
 },
    {
  "name": "hello",
  "domain": "domain2",
  "subdomain": "subdomain6",
  "type": "no",
        "desc":"hello"
 },
     {
  "name": "hello",
  "domain": "domain5",
  "subdomain": "subdomain6",
  "type": "no",
        "desc":"hello"
 }
    
];

var namesearch = ["he"];
var domain = ["domain5","domain2"];
var result = data.filter((d)=>{
return (namesearch.length > 0 ? namesearch[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(d.name.toLowerCase()) > -1:'') &&  domain.length > 0 ? domain.includes(d.domain):''
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

way of indexOf call is wrong. Try this `d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(namesearch[0].toLowerCase())`

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "test",
    domain: "domain1",
    subdomain: "subdomain1",
    type: "yes"
  },
  {
    name: "hello",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no"
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "helloo"
  }
];

var namesearch = ["he"];
var domain = ["domain5", "domain2"];
var result = data.filter(d => {
  return (namesearch.length > 0
    ? d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(namesearch[0].toLowerCase()) > -1
    : "") && domain.length > 0
    ? domain.includes(d.domain)
    : "";
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using too many ternary expression that i don't see utility,
I prefer before filtering testing on namesearch.length because if length is 0 you're not obliged to enter filter block.

```
 var data = [ {
            "name": "test",
            "domain": "domain2",
            "subdomain": "subdomain5",
            "type": "yes"
        },
        {
            "name": "test",
            "domain": "domain2",
            "subdomain": "subdomain6",
            "type": "no"
        },
        {
            "name": "hello",
            "domain": "domain2",
            "subdomain": "subdomain6",
            "type": "no"
        },
        {
            "name": "hello",
            "domain": "domain2",
            "subdomain": "subdomain6",
            "type": "no",
            "desc":"hello"
        },
         {
            "name": "hello",
            "domain": "domain5",
            "subdomain": "subdomain6",
            "type": "no",
            "desc":"hello"
        }

    ];

    var namesearch = ["he"];
    var domain = ["domain5","domain2"];
    if (namesearch.length > 0) {
        var result = data.filter((d)=>{

        return ( d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(namesearch[0].toLowerCase()) > -1) &&  domain.length > 0 && domain.includes(d.domain)
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
```

Comment: namesearch is optional some times we need to use inside the filter only. and domain also optional